# IPython Notebook: unnecessary scrollbars in output_area when using `display(Latex(...`

Tags: css, jupyter-notebook

I have the following modification to the notebook style sheet

```
.output_area {font-size: 101%;}
```

i.e., I'm slightly increasing the size of the default font.

Using `print(...` I have absolutely no problem, while using `display(Latex(...` I have what looks like a totally unnecessary scrollbar, see picture below, where you can also see (part of) the code that produced the output.

[image]

Is it possible to increase the size of the fonts in the `output_area` without introducing the unnecessary scrollbar?

Tx in advance, g

**Edit:** I forgot to mention, w/o the css modification there is no scrollbar...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `overflow: hidden;` in the css (I do it for pre as well)

I think this will mess up really long output cells but I don't have any.

You can also use `div.output_latex {...}` to format only latex, which is really mathjax in the browser.

The easiest way to figure it out is to right click on the part you want in Chrome and choose developer tools (other browsers may have similar tools).

[image]

You can see that the overflow is last set in output_subarea so you have to overwrite it after that block is read.  You can make another style section "output_subarea" or just put it in the "output_latex" section.

The "output_area" section is the whole wrapper for output including the place with Out[nn]: .

Comment: For me the only `CSS` mod that does the trick is `div.output_latex{overflow:hidden}`, any other attempt at setting the `overflow` property is pointless (is the last word said at the level of `.output_latex`?). I want to mention that I've found that `font-size` modifications like in `div.output_area{font-size:130%;}` followed by `div.output_latex{font-size:130%;}` are cumulative, leading to a LaTeX output magnified at 169%... That's obvious if you think of it but if you don't... Brian, If you like to edit your answer to reflect these findings I'll accept it, for now I'm just upvoting, Thanks